# Query to Copy Rows to Yearly Summary, need unique identifier for each row in the yearly summary but need to be specific to the individual rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to get a formula to create a unique identifier in the yearly summary tab of my excel document. Right now if I add rows into the individual tabs then the rows copy over in order to the yearly summary and my unique identifier changes. How can I get my unique identifier to be specific to a certain row to where if there are adds later then they will add to the bottom and have a new unique identifier. Do I need to adjust my query or do I need to adjust my Formula?

All my weeks are added in per tab per week. All the information is added in here.

[image: Week 3]

Then I have a query to bring it all to the yearly summary tab. The formula I am using for my unique identifier is below:

''' ="24-"&IF([@[Sheet Name]]>"",COUNTA($N$2:N2),"") '''

[image: Yearly Summary]

So my question is, does the formula need to change or does the query need to change? I want any new additions to any week to transfer over to the yearly summary in order of addition, not in order of week.

Comment: It seems to me your query is making the order. The formula just follows that order. But without seeing the query code or an example of adding data and what happens versus what you expect, it's hard to tell.